# UIScrollView starts automatically in double size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an image that I want to display fullscreen in my app using UIScrollView and UIImageView, the image size is 640 x 2754 and I want to show it automatically in full screen mode in minimum zoom.

This is the code:

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"EquationPage.png"]]; self.imageView = tempImageView;
[tempImageView release];
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(640,2754);
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

scrollView.delegate = self;
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: And your question is…?

Comment: "I want to show it automatically in full screen mode in minimum zoom"

Comment: you have described what is happening, but forgot to ask your question. what is it that you want to be solved?

Comment: The image comes automatically in the maximumZoom and i want to know how i can show it in the minimumZoom automatically

Comment: `[scrollView setZoomScale:0.5 animated:NO];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you will have to use the `setZoomScale:animated:` method of `UIScrollView`. Confusingly, this method will not work unless you have a (non-nil) delegate set for your scroll view, which responds to `-viewForZoomingInScrollView`. Read the [UIScrollView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) for how to do this. For more info, you can also read [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html) about handling zooming with a `UIScrollView`.